# How to show Grid at Data view?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1

I need to use Grid of local cooridante system at data view in order to improve georeferencing process of old map. how to make it visible, without convert it to graphics ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grids can be viewed in Layout view only.

Your options are converting it to graphics, but you could also [convert the graphics to feature class](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s900000008000000) so you could use the grid in multiple documents just by adding a layer (since graphics objects are stored in .mxd documents only).